# Python regex sub

Tags: python, regex

I want to delete all comment. This is my regular expression :

```
re.sub(re.compile('<!--.*-->', re.DOTALL),'', text)
```

But if my text is :

```
bzzzzzz <!-- blabla --> blibli <!-- bloblo --> blublu
```

the result is :

```
bzzzzzz blublu
```

instead of :

```
bzzzzzz blibli blublu
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`*` is greedy while `*?` is not

```
re.sub(re.compile('<!--.*?-->', re.DOTALL), '', text)
```

or, even shorter:

```
re.sub('(?s)<!--.*?-->', '', text)
```

Answer (score 11):

I'd suggest not to use regex for this kind of stuff. There is always a better solution, such as [lxml.html.clean](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#cleaning-up-html).

Your example:

```
import lxml.html.clean as clean
cleaner = clean.Cleaner(comments=True)
cleaner.clean_html("bzzzzzz <!-- blabla --> blibli <!-- bloblo --> blublu")
#'bzzzzzz  blibli  blublu'
```